# rxjs: load many for many from 2 endpoints and merge into single Observable

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have one endpoint for getting list of users, and another for getting list of apartments for every user:

```
getUsers() => Observable<User[]>;
getUserApartments(userId) => Observable<Apartment[]>`
```

How do I merge the data from the two into single observable:

```
const usersWithApartments$: Observable<{ user: User, apartments: Apartment[] }[]> = getUsers().pipe(
    // users.map(user => { user, apartments: getUserApartments(user.id) }) <-- turn this pseudocode into Rxjs
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `getUsers()`'s return type is `Users[]` I'm assuming the desired type is collection of `{ user: User, apartments: Apartment[]>` rather than a single one.

Please consider the below implementation:

```js
class UserApartments {
  user: User;
  apartments: Apartment[];
}
```

```js
const usersWithApartments$: Observable<UserApartments[]> = getUsers()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(users => forkJoin(
      users.map(user => getUserApartments(user.id).pipe(
        map(apartments => ({ user, apartments }))
      ))
    ))
  );
```

Comment: correct! fixed it in the question. And thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

```
const toUserWithApartmentsStream = (user: User) => getUserApartments(user.id).pipe(
  map((apartments: Apartment[]) => ({ user, apartments }))
);

const usersWithApartments$: Observable<{ user: User, apartments: Apartment[] }[]> =
  getUsers().pipe(
    switchMap((users: User[]) => users),
    concatMap((user: User) => toUserWithApartmentsStream(user)),
    toArray()
  );
```

Right now `getUserApartments` will be executed consecutively one by one, I could write `mergeMap` instead of `concatMap` and the `getUserApartments` will be executed concurrently. Thanks Rafi Henig for the comment

The function `toUserWithApartmentsStream` is just a helper, so that code looks cleaner. I could just write it inline inside the `concatMap`.

Comment: Your solution suffers from a lack of concurrency

Comment: @RafiHenig What if the author doesn't want concurrently sending lots of requests to the api? I wouldn't say this answer lacks concurrency, I would say that this specific answer is going to execute requests consecutively to avoid sending too much requests at the same time and making things worse. As for an alternative, I could write `mergeMap` instead of `switchMap` and my answer will have concurrency.

Comment: `@Goga Koreli` usually concurrency is desired, in addition `mergeMap` doesn't guarantee that the merged observable will emit the api responses in the same order as items from the source arrive

Comment: I agree, usually it is. In the real world scenario for this specific example, if there are lots of users, it would cause sending lots of network calls concurrently and if there are multiple authenticated users doing this same time, it will be even more. Thus hitting the backend way hard. Btw, I agree mergeMap doesn't guarantee the order of arrival, but I don't see a reason to mention it when the result is an array in both cases.